# Python question on elementwise operation

Tags: python

I have two srtings of integer a=[-1,0,-1,0,1] and b=[1] and i want to subtract b from a as elementwise operation but the answer shoud be string contaning element -1 or 0 or 1

Comment: I don't have any idea what that is supposed to mean. Can you give an example ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the function output should be?

Comment: When you say "string" do you mean "list"?

Comment: I can't tell if you want [-1,-1,-1,-1,0] or [-1,0,-1,0] or something else. You need to clarify your question

Comment: FWIW, the original title (edited out) contained b=[-1] instead of b=[1]. Maybe it's actually substracting elementwise. (and, once again, I'm hopelessly trying to decipher/reverse engineer/analyze a question)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean this:

```
def elementwise_subtraction_of_strings_of_integer(a, b):
    c = b * (len(a) // len(b))
    return [aa - bb for aa, bb in zip(a, c)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=[-1,0,-1,0,1]
    b=[1]
    print elementwise_subtraction_of_strings_of_integer(a, b)
```

It produces this:

```
[-2, -1, -2, -1, 0]
```

If this is not what you want, please rephrase the question as several commenters have suggested.

Comment: If I had 25K in reputation, I'd have just fixed the typo.

Comment: I thought it was intentional -- a subtle joke.